# 'NSManagedObject.h' file not found - theos compile error

Tags: ios, tweak, theos

Hi I'm trying to create a patch for an iOS Game and i'm getting the following error when i try to compile:

```
In file included from Tweak.xm:6:
/../.../X.h:7:9: fatal error: 'NSManagedObject.h' file not found
#import "NSManagedObject.h"
        ^
6 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.41a2083e.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [xxx.all.tweak.variables] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`NSManagedObject` is declared in the `CoreData` framework, so you have to link it when compiling.

In your makefile you have to put something like

```
<YOURPATCH>_FRAMEWORKS = CoreData
```

Comment: thanks for your reply
i have 

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h> 

at the start of the tweak.xm is that not enough?
also do you mean make_frameworks = CoreData?

thanks

Comment: Importing is not enough if you don't link the framework. Also I haven't being using theos for a while but yes `make_frameworks` should do.